# exporting Jsfiddle to upload to website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have used `jsfiddle` for most of my projects, but I can't seem to export this one:

https://jsfiddle.net/wayneker/29ocq0q8/show

When I export it and save it to my website, all the timings are blank. 
I have used the save webpage, show frame code and copy/paste into a new page and also, I have used `notepad++` to copy it to and run as file using browser options.

Could someone please tell me what i am doing wrong as none of the timevalues actually run. http://www.ahoymearty.co.uk/calculators/index2.html

```
var datetime = null,
        raidDate = '15/06/2017',
        date = null;

var alpha = moment('01/01/00 17:00:00').format('HH:mm:ss');
var beta = moment('01/01/00 18:00:00').format('HH:mm:ss');
var gamma = moment('01/01/00 19:00:00').format('HH:mm:ss');
var delta = moment('01/01/00 20:00:00').format('HH:mm:ss');
var epsilon = moment('01/01/00 21:00:00').format('HH:mm:ss');

var raidDateAlpha = moment.utc(raidDate + ' ' + alpha, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
var raidDateBeta = moment.utc(raidDate + ' ' + beta, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
var raidDateGamma = moment.utc(raidDate + ' ' + gamma, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
var raidDateDelta = moment.utc(raidDate + ' ' + delta, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');
var raidDateEpsilon= moment.utc(raidDate + ' ' + epsilon, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm');

$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    var divUtc = $('#divUTC');
    var divLocal = $('.divLocal');  
    //put UTC time into divUTC  
    divUtc.text(moment.utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));      

    //get text from divUTC and conver to local timezone  
    var localTime  = moment.utc(divUtc.text()).toDate();
    localTime = moment(localTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
    divLocal.text(localTime);        
  },1000);
});


(function timerLoop() {
  $(".alpha").text(countdown(raidDateAlpha).toString());
  $(".beta").text(countdown(raidDateBeta).toString());
  $(".gamma").text(countdown(raidDateGamma).toString());  
  $(".delta").text(countdown(raidDateDelta).toString()); 
  $(".epsilon").text(countdown(raidDateEpsilon).toString());

  datetime = $('.datetime') 
  requestAnimationFrame(timerLoop);
})();

var HEMISPHERE_SOUTH = 'SOUTH';
var HEMISPHERE_NORTH = 'NORTH';
var HEMISPHERE_UNKNOWN = 'N/A';
var olson = {}

/**
 * The keys in this dictionary are comma separated as such:
 * 
 * First the offset compared to UTC time in minutes.
 *  
 * Then a flag which is 0 if the timezone does not take daylight savings into account and 1 if it does.
 * 
 * Thirdly an optional 's' signifies that the timezone is in the southern hemisphere, only interesting for timezones with DST.
 * 
 * The values of the dictionary are TimeZone objects.
 */
olson.timezones = {
    '-720,0'   : new TimeZone('-12:00','Etc/GMT+12', false),
    '-660,0'   : new TimeZone('-11:00','Pacific/Pago_Pago', false),
    '-600,1'   : new TimeZone('-11:00','America/Adak',true),
    '-660,1,s' : new TimeZone('-11:00','Pacific/Apia', true),
    '-600,0'   : new TimeZone('-10:00','Pacific/Honolulu', false),
    '-570,0'   : new TimeZone('-10:30','Pacific/Marquesas',false),
    '-540,0'   : new TimeZone('-09:00','Pacific/Gambier',false),
    '-540,1'   : new TimeZone('-09:00','America/Anchorage', true),
    '-480,1'   : new TimeZone('-08:00','America/Los_Angeles', true),
    '-480,0'   : new TimeZone('-08:00','Pacific/Pitcairn',false),
    '-420,0'   : new TimeZone('-07:00','America/Phoenix', false),
    '-420,1'   : new TimeZone('-07:00','America/Denver', true),
    '-360,0'   : new TimeZone('-06:00','America/Guatemala', false),
    '-360,1'   : new TimeZone('-06:00','America/Chicago', true),
    '-360,1,s' : new TimeZone('-06:00','Pacific/Easter',true),
    '-300,0'   : new TimeZone('-05:00','America/Bogota', false),
    '-300,1'   : new TimeZone('-05:00','America/New_York', true),
    '-270,0'   : new TimeZone('-04:30','America/Caracas', false),
    '-240,1'   : new TimeZone('-04:00','America/Halifax', true),
    '-240,0'   : new TimeZone('-04:00','America/Santo_Domingo', false),
    '-240,1,s' : new TimeZone('-04:00','America/Asuncion', true),
    '-210,1'   : new TimeZone('-03:30','America/St_Johns', true),
    '-180,1'   : new TimeZone('-03:00','America/Godthab', true),
    '-180,0'   : new TimeZone('-03:00','America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires,', false),
    '-180,1,s' : new TimeZone('-03:00','America/Montevideo', true),
    '-120,0'   : new TimeZone('-02:00','America/Noronha', false),
    '-120,1'   : new TimeZone('-02:00','Etc/GMT+2', true),
    '-60,1'    : new TimeZone('-01:00','Atlantic/Azores', true),
    '-60,0'    : new TimeZone('-01:00','Atlantic/Cape_Verde', false),
    '0,0'      : new TimeZone('00:00','Africa/Casablanca', false),
    '0,1'      : new TimeZone('00:00','Europe/London', true),
    '60,1'     : new TimeZone('+01:00','Europe/Berlin', true),
    '60,0'     : new TimeZone('+01:00','Africa/Lagos', false),
    '60,1,s'   : new TimeZone('+01:00','Africa/Windhoek',true),
    '120,1'    : new TimeZone('+02:00','Asia/Beirut', true),
    '120,0'    : new TimeZone('+02:00','Africa/Johannesburg', false),
    '180,1'    : new TimeZone('+03:00','Europe/Moscow', true),
    '180,0'    : new TimeZone('+03:00','Asia/Baghdad', false),
    '210,1'    : new TimeZone('+03:30','Asia/Tehran', true),
    '240,0'    : new TimeZone('+04:00','Asia/Dubai', false),
    '240,1'    : new TimeZone('+04:00','Asia/Yerevan', true),
    '270,0'    : new TimeZone('+04:30','Asia/Kabul', false),
    '300,1'    : new TimeZone('+05:00','Asia/Yekaterinburg', true),
    '300,0'    : new TimeZone('+05:00','Asia/Karachi', false),
    '330,0'    : new TimeZone('+05:30','Asia/Kolkata', false),
    '345,0'    : new TimeZone('+05:45','Asia/Kathmandu', false),
    '360,0'    : new TimeZone('+06:00','Asia/Dhaka', false),
    '360,1'    : new TimeZone('+06:00','Asia/Omsk', true),
    '390,0'    : new TimeZone('+06:30','Asia/Rangoon', false),
    '420,1'    : new TimeZone('+07:00','Asia/Krasnoyarsk', true),
    '420,0'    : new TimeZone('+07:00','Asia/Jakarta', false),
    '480,0'    : new TimeZone('+08:00','Asia/Shanghai', false),
    '480,1'    : new TimeZone('+08:00','Asia/Irkutsk', true),
    '525,0'    : new TimeZone('+08:45','Australia/Eucla', true),
    '525,1,s'  : new TimeZone('+08:45','Australia/Eucla', true),
    '540,1'    : new TimeZone('+09:00','Asia/Yakutsk', true),
    '540,0'    : new TimeZone('+09:00','Asia/Tokyo', false),
    '570,0'    : new TimeZone('+09:30','Australia/Darwin', false),
    '570,1,s'  : new TimeZone('+09:30','Australia/Adelaide', true),
    '600,0'    : new TimeZone('+10:00','Australia/Brisbane', false),
    '600,1'    : new TimeZone('+10:00','Asia/Vladivostok', true),
    '600,1,s'  : new TimeZone('+10:00','Australia/Sydney', true),
    '630,1,s'  : new TimeZone('+10:30','Australia/Lord_Howe', true),
    '660,1'    : new TimeZone('+11:00','Asia/Kamchatka', true),
    '660,0'    : new TimeZone('+11:00','Pacific/Noumea', false),
    '690,0'    : new TimeZone('+11:30','Pacific/Norfolk', false),
    '720,1,s'  : new TimeZone('+12:00','Pacific/Auckland', true),
    '720,0'    : new TimeZone('+12:00','Pacific/Tarawa', false),
    '765,1,s'  : new TimeZone('+12:45','Pacific/Chatham', true),
    '780,0'    : new TimeZone('+13:00','Pacific/Tongatapu', false),
    '840,0'    : new TimeZone('+14:00','Pacific/Kiritimati', false)
}

/**
 * This object contains information on when daylight savings starts for
 * different timezones.
 * 
 * The list is short for a reason. Often we do not have to be very specific
 * to single out the correct timezone. But when we do, this list comes in
 * handy.
 * 
 * Each value is a date denoting when daylight savings starts for that timezone.
 */
olson.dst_start_dates = {
    'America/Denver' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Mazatlan' : new Date(2011, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Chicago' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Mexico_City' : new Date(2011, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'Atlantic/Stanley' : new Date(2011, 8, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Asuncion' : new Date(2011, 9, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Santiago' : new Date(2011, 9, 9, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Campo_Grande' : new Date(2011, 9, 16, 5, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Montevideo' : new Date(2011, 9, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Sao_Paolo' : new Date(2011, 9, 16, 5, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Los_Angeles' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 8, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Santa_Isabel' : new Date(2011, 3, 5, 8, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Havana' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 2, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/New_York' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 7, 0, 0, 0),
    'Asia/Gaza' : new Date(2011, 2, 26, 23, 0, 0, 0),
    'Asia/Beirut' : new Date(2011, 2, 27, 1, 0, 0, 0),
    'Europe/Minsk' : new Date(2011, 2, 27, 3, 0, 0, 0),
    'Europe/Istanbul' : new Date(2011, 2, 27, 7, 0, 0, 0),
    'Asia/Damascus' : new Date(2011, 3, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0),
    'Asia/Jerusalem' : new Date(2011, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 0),
    'Africa/Cairo' : new Date(2011, 3, 29, 4, 0, 0, 0),
    'Asia/Yerevan' : new Date(2011, 2, 27, 4, 0, 0, 0),
    'Asia/Baku'    : new Date(2011, 2, 27, 8, 0, 0, 0),
    'Pacific/Auckland' : new Date(2011, 8, 26, 7, 0, 0, 0),
    'Pacific/Fiji' : new Date(2010, 11, 29, 23, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Halifax' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 6, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Goose_Bay' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 2, 1, 0, 0),
    'America/Miquelon' : new Date(2011, 2, 13, 5, 0, 0, 0),
    'America/Godthab' : new Date(2011, 2, 27, 1, 0, 0, 0)
}

/**
 * The keys in this object are timezones that we know may be ambiguous after
 * a preliminary scan through the olson_tz object.
 * 
 * The array of timezones to compare must be in the order that daylight savings
 * starts for the regions.
 */
olson.ambiguity_list = {
    'America/Denver' : ['America/Denver','America/Mazatlan'],
    'America/Chicago' : ['America/Chicago','America/Mexico_City'],
    'America/Asuncion' : ['Atlantic/Stanley', 'America/Asuncion', 'America/Santiago','America/Campo_Grande'],
    'America/Montevideo' : ['America/Montevideo', 'America/Sao_Paolo'],
    'Asia/Beirut' : ['Asia/Gaza','Asia/Beirut', 'Europe/Minsk', 'Europe/Istanbul', 'Asia/Damascus', 'Asia/Jerusalem','Africa/Cairo'],
    'Asia/Yerevan' : ['Asia/Yerevan', 'Asia/Baku'],
    'Pacific/Auckland' : ['Pacific/Auckland', 'Pacific/Fiji'],
    'America/Los_Angeles' : ['America/Los_Angeles', 'America/Santa_Isabel'],
    'America/New_York' : ['America/Havana','America/New_York'],
    'America/Halifax' : ['America/Goose_Bay','America/Halifax'],
    'America/Godthab' : ['America/Miquelon', 'America/Godthab']
}


/**
 * A simple object containing information of utc_offset, which olson timezone key to use, 
 * and if the timezone cares about daylight savings or not.
 * 
 * @constructor
 * @param {string} offset - for example '-11:00'
 * @param {string} olson_tz - the olson Identifier, such as "America/Denver"
 * @param {boolean} uses_dst - flag for whether the time zone somehow cares about daylight savings.
 */
function TimeZone(offset, olson_tz, uses_dst) {
    this.utc_offset = offset;
    this.olson_tz = olson_tz;
    this.uses_dst = uses_dst;
}

/**
 * Prints out the result.
 * But before it does that, it calls this.ambiguity_check.
 */
TimeZone.prototype.display = function() {
    this.ambiguity_check();
    var response_text = '<b>UTC-offset</b>: ' + this.utc_offset + '<br/>';
    response_text += '<b>Location Detected As</b>: ' + this.olson_tz + '<br/>';
    response_text += '<b>Daylight Savings</b>: ' + (this.uses_dst ? 'yes' : 'no') + '<br/>';

 //   var response_text2 =  (this.uses_dst ? 'yes' : 'no');
 //   alert(response_text2);

    return response_text;
}



/**
 * Checks if a timezone has possible ambiguities. I.e timezones that are similar.
 * 
 * If the preliminary scan determines that we're in America/Denver. We double check
 * here that we're really there and not in America/Mazatlan.
 * 
 * This is done by checking known dates for when daylight savings start for different
 * timezones.
 */
TimeZone.prototype.ambiguity_check = function() {
    var local_ambiguity_list = olson.ambiguity_list[this.olson_tz];

    if (typeof(local_ambiguity_list) == 'undefined') {
        return;
    }

    var length = local_ambiguity_list.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        var tz = local_ambiguity_list[i]

        if (date_is_dst(olson.dst_start_dates[tz])) {
            this.olson_tz = tz;
            return;
        }    
    }
}

/**
 * Checks whether a given date is in daylight savings time.
 * 
 * If the date supplied is after june, we assume that we're checking
 * for southern hemisphere DST.
 * 
 * @param {Date} date
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
function date_is_dst(date) {
    var base_offset = ( (date.getMonth() > 5 ? get_june_offset() : get_january_offset()) )

    var date_offset = get_date_offset(date);

    return (base_offset - date_offset) != 0;
}

/** 
 * Gets the offset in minutes from UTC for a certain date.
 * 
 * @param date
 * @returns {number}
 */
function get_date_offset(date) {
    return -date.getTimezoneOffset();
}

/**
 * This function does some basic calculations to create information about 
 * the user's timezone.
 * 
 * Returns a primitive object on the format
 * {'utc_offset' : -9, 'dst': 1, hemisphere' : 'north'}
 * where dst is 1 if the region uses daylight savings.
 * 
 * @returns {Object}  
 */
function get_timezone_info() {
    var january_offset = get_january_offset();
    var june_offset = get_june_offset();

    var diff = january_offset - june_offset;

    if (diff < 0) {
        return {'utc_offset' : january_offset,
                'dst':    1,
                'hemisphere' : HEMISPHERE_NORTH}
    }
    else if (diff > 0) {
        return {'utc_offset' : june_offset,
                'dst' : 1,
                'hemisphere' : HEMISPHERE_SOUTH}
    }

    return {'utc_offset' : january_offset, 
            'dst': 0, 
            'hemisphere' : HEMISPHERE_UNKNOWN}
}

function get_january_offset() {
    return get_date_offset(new Date(2011, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
}

function get_june_offset() {
    return get_date_offset(new Date(2011, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0));
}

/**
 * Uses get_timezone_info() to formulate a key to use in the olson.timezones dictionary.
 * 
 * Returns a primitive object on the format:
 * {'timezone': TimeZone, 'key' : 'the key used to find the TimeZone object'}
 * 
 * @returns Object 
 */
function determine_timezone() {
    var timezone_key_info = get_timezone_info();

    var hemisphere_suffix = ''

    if (timezone_key_info.hemisphere == HEMISPHERE_SOUTH) {
        hemisphere_suffix = ',s';
    }

    var tz_key = timezone_key_info.utc_offset + ',' + timezone_key_info.dst + hemisphere_suffix

    return {'timezone' : olson.timezones[tz_key], 'key' : tz_key}
}

/**
 * This is the entry point of the application.
 */
function show_timezone_info() {
    var tz_info = determine_timezone();

    response_text = 'No timezone found for ' + tz_info.key;

    if (typeof(tz_info.timezone) == 'undefined') {
        response_text = 'No timezone found for ' + tz_info.key;
    }
    else {
        response_text = tz_info.timezone.display(); 
    }

    document.getElementById('tz_info').innerHTML = response_text
}

show_timezone_info();
```

Comment: Have you linked jQuery in your local copy? It's not obvious from JSFiddle as jQuery is listed under an external resource, catches me out pretty often :-)

Comment: I think so         <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>

Comment: In the end i just copied the whole code that showed in the frame and still didnt work for me

Comment: You've got a load of missing resources in your local copy. Open up your developer console (F12/Ctrl+shift+J in Chrome) and take a look at the `404` warnings.

Comment: how come there are errors then... I just copied everything in the frame window?

Answer (score 0):

I sorted it. The mootools was pointing to a file on my web which didnt exist rather than using a resource. So I added a local copy.

/js/lib/mootools-core-1.3-full-compat-nc.js